# Enabling Autocomplete on Atom Editor

Tags: atom-editor

First off, I don't know what this is called. So I am going to explain it.

While using Sublime Text Editor and editing HTML it would autocomplete certain parts of the text. Stuff it knew without a doubt that I would be typing.

For example:

```
<div> </
```

By the time I've typed that, it would auto-complete to

```
<div> </div>
```

Now, I'm wondering what this is called and how I can enable this when using Atom.

I know this is probably a silly question, but I have looked through the answers myself and I just don't know what this is called in actuality, so I can't seem to find anything related to it and it would probably be faster to get a quick answer here.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you know you can just type `div` and press Tab to create both tags?

Comment: There is an issue for this: https://github.com/atom/language-html/issues/63

Comment: Hey, this has been a great help. Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at this package https://atom.io/package/tag

Answer (score 3):

U can type the command without braces it will automatically complete the tags... I tried it and works well...

ex: write p instead of

Hope you understand.....

cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this from inside the Atom Editor. See my Atom Cheatsheet at https://github.com/pd-gmit/atom-cheatsheet/blob/master/atom_cheatsheet.md for more tips.

**Ctrl Space L**